# Is there an easier way to access private scoped variable?

Tags: powershell, scope, private-members

Currently I am using the following syntax to explicitly access a private scoped variable, inside of a PowerShell function:

```
function MyPowershellFunction {
    param($param1)
    # ...
    # lot of code here
    # ...

    # access variable x on private scope explicitly
    if ($private:x) {
         # do something
    }
}
```

I am doing this so that I do not accidentally refer to a variable defined in parent scope. But the code looks ugly by having private all around. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3):

By making a variable `private` you restrict its visibility to the current scope. Since variables are looked up in the current scope first `$x` should give you the private variable after it was initially declared `private` as long as you don't leave the scope. Using the scope modifier all the time shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: To add to Ansgar's answer, private scoping is to prevent any child scope from seeing the variable.  If you're using it inside a function that's not invoking any child scopes then there's nothing to hide it from.

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers Thanks. But I am having to use `$private:x` (or say `$private:ALongVariableName`) to make sure I do not make a typo and accidentally access a variable in some parent scope named `$ALongVeriableName`. Because Powershell does not complain about undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Local scope modifier:

```
function MyPowershellFunction {
    param($param1)

    # access variable x on private scope explicitly
    if ($local:x) {
         # do something
    }
}
```

The if statement does not see any $x defined in the parent scope.